# recognize dll on any computer on server

Tags: vb.net, excel, com, publish, vba

I have a vb.net class library made in visual studio that I've made COM visible and it is recognizable through excel vba on my computer. The next step I need to take is allowing anyone at the office to have the capability of referencing the class library from their computer in an excel document and I am not sure how to accomplish this. I have read a little bit about *publishing* the class library, however that option is not available for me to click on in visual studio for my class library. Any push in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the assembly to each computer and then register it for COM with `regasm`.  If your assembly has other assemblies upon which it is dependent, and they are not in the GAC, you'll need to use the `/codebase` option when registering it.

Comment: Still reading up and messing around with this trying to get it to work. I will accept the answer if this ends up working (I believe it should)

Comment: If changes are made to my vb.net code and I need to update the .dll file to be recognized, can I just call regasm again without any complications?

Comment: Once it is registered, you should be able to simply replace the file without re-registering.  The only time you'd need to re-register it would be if you change any of the public interfaces in the library.  But, yes, you can just run regasm again to re-register.